# Using same serialport on two different forms

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have two forms = Form1.CS and SMS.CS
on the first form (Form1) i've configured and ready to work serialport1. I have button which is called send message. This button opens new form called SMS.cs.

```
private void SMS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SMS settings = new SMS();
        settings.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I'd like to use my configured serialport1 on to forms: Form1 and form SMS.cs. It's also possible to receive from form SMS data, and send it using serialport1 on Form1 for example:

```
 private void SMS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SMS settings = new SMS();
        settings.ShowDialog();
        SerialPort1.Writeln(Data from form SMS)
    }
```

but i don't know how to do it. The best idea in my opinion is to send data directly from SMS form..

Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class SMSForm : Form
    {
        SerialPort SerialP;

        public SMSForm(Object SerialP)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            SerialP.WriteLine("ATI");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form1 is the SerialPort controller - that is, Form1 configures SerialPort. If you have an event that affects SerialPort, such as `SerialPort1.Writeln', you should pass a method reference to the dialog constuctor. This will logically keep classes separate while *sharing* methods.

You can create a custom EventArgs object to pass the string back to your SerialPort:

```
public class WriteToSerialPortEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public WriteToSerialPortEventArgs (string Write)
    { WriteBytes = Encoding.GetBytes(write); }  // simplified - see MSDN for more options 

    public byte[] WriteBytes
    { get; private set; }   
}
```

`Form1` sample event delegate passed to your SMS dialog:

```
void OnWriteToSerialPort(object sender, WriteToSerialPortEventArgs e )
{
    SerialPort1.WriteLine(e.WriteBytes);
}
```

Write your SMS constructor:

```
// field
Action<object, WriteToSerialPortEventArgs> writeDelegate;

public SMS (Action<object, WriteToSerialPortEventArgs> writeDelegate)
{
    this.writeDelegate = writeDelegate;
    this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
}
```

... SMS event delegate:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    writeDelegate.Invoke(sender, new WriteToSerialPortEventArgs (txtBox.Text);
}
```

Technically, you don't need the full `Invoke(...)` method signature. I included it for completeness and can be written as:

```
writeDelegate(sender, new WriteToSerialPortEventArgs (txtBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the same SerialPort in two forms you need to send the reference to the SerialPort to the second form.

The simplest way is to add a new constructor to the SMS form which accepts a SerialPort, store it in a member variable and use it.

Where you do

```
SMS settings = new SMS();
```

you will need to actually do this:

```
SMS settings = new SMS(SerialPort1);
```

Comment: I was trying this way earlier, but there was error: error CS1729: 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SMSForm' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Elfoc: Show us how you've defined the constructor. The error message suggests you didn't...

Comment: I didn't do this :) In edit i was trying to defined this constructor but with problems :) I've had only more time for basics.. :(

Comment: @Elfoc: Why do you use "object SerialP" if you really need to send a SerialPort object? Use the full type. Also, I told you to store, in the constructor, the parameter to a member variable; where are you doing this?

Comment: Damn. I don't know how to do this properly.. could you just write me this part of code?